# Custom each loop in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

- ruby 2.0.0p247
- Rails 4.0.0

How to alternate the html content of my loop?

```
- @recipes.each do |recipe|
    = image_tag "path.png", :height => "?", :width => "?"
```

Fox example:

The output expected is like:

```
image_tag "medium-01.png", :height => "200", :width => "350"

image_tag "small-02.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
image_tag "small03.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
image_tag "small-04.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
image_tag "small-05.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"

image_tag "medium-06.png", :height => "200", :width => "350"
image_tag "medium-07.png", :height => "200", :width => "350"

image_tag "small-08.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
image_tag "small-09.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
```

**Result desired bellow:**

[image]

In jquery I did this. Maybe helps:

```
$("div").each(function(i, element) {
    if (i % 5 == 0 || i % 6 == 0) {
        $(this).css({"background":"dark_gray_color"});
    }
    else {
        $(this).css({"background":"magenta_color"});
    }
});
```

Am I clear?

Comment: Couple of questions: Where are image names coming from? Where do the height and width values come from? How would you match the numeric index values to the correct path (for example, what happens if `@recipes` is in a different order, and you end up with `small-01.png` instead of `medium-01.png`..etc)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ruby's [`Enumerable#each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) to get a loop similar to the jquery one you posted.

```
@recipes.each_with_index do |recipe, i|
  if [0,5,6].include? i
    h, w = 200, 350
  else
    h, w = 183, 285
  end

  image_tag "path.png", :height => "#{h}", :width => "#{w}"
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know the "each_with_index". Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

This code should get the output you desire. Not sure I have HAML right(not tested).

```
- @recipes.each.with_index do |recipe, i|
  - if [i, i % 5, i % 6].any?(&:zero?)
      = image_tag "medium-#{'%02d' % (i + 1)}.png", :height => "200", :width => "350"
  - else
      = image_tag "small-#{'%02d' % (i + 1)}.png", :height => "183", :width => "285"
  - end
```